# List AD Users in InfoPath Form

Tags: active-directory

I've found many posts on how to return the current user's AD information in an InfoPath Form - but I require a list of AD Users.

Furthermore, this is to be accomplished in a browser-enabled form accessed within a MOSS website.

Is there an AD webservice that can be used to return this info?

Answer (score 0):

No, there' no web service available for AD out of the box that I'm aware of. However, it would be relatively simple to create one yourself.

There's a number of places to get started, if you're interested:

- [System.DirectoryServices portal on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms817845.aspx)
- [DirectoryProgramming.net web site](http://www.directoryprogramming.net/)
- [Joe Kaplan and Ryan Dunn's excellent book on .NET DirectoryServices programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321350170)

[image: Book on .NET Directory Services Programming]

- [Query Active Directory](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/activedirquery.aspx)
- [How to do (almost) everything in Active Directory](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx)

Unfortunately, nothing is really "ready-made" - just plug it in and use it :-(

Marc

Answer (score 0):

If all users are in "domain users" group, you can use usergroup.asmx to get your list of all AD users.

Comment: Can you please share the steps?